# how to change the value of a extern variable that is present in another file?

Tags: c, static, global, extern

I have defined a static integer in head.h as shown below.

//head.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
static int a = 100;
```

i m executing both programs one.c and two.c simultaneously in two terminals, first one.c since i gave a getchar() its waiting to get an input from stdin.

//one.c

```
#include "head.h"

extern int a;
int main(void)
{
     getchar();
     printf("Value of a : %d\n", a);
     return 0;
}
```

while the one.c is waiting i executed two.c, which changes the value of a to 80, i have declared 'a' as static in head.c so it has only one memory to store the value no copies are created. pressed ENTER, two.c printed the value of a is 80. but now when Pressed Enter in one.c it still prints 100.

//two.c

```
 #include "head.h"

 extern int a;
 int main(void)
 {
     a = 80;
     getchar();
     printf("Value of a : %d\n", a);
     return 0;
 }
```

why is this not working, and if there is an alternative way to change the extern variables please tell me.

Comment: Two separate C programs do not share *any* variables unless you make some specific calls to the OS to share memory between the two programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different processes can not see the address space of each other, because the i386 is specially made so as to protect the process address space.

if you need two different process and shared memory for each, then you need threads, it is not a processes, but it have similar behavior.

Oh, of course you can still use the standard input output like this:

in 1-st proc: `printf("%d\n", send);`
in 2-st proc: `scanf("%d", &recv);`

but for this to work, you must run the program as follows:

> ./proc1 | ./proc2

but **not** `./proc2| ./proc1` and not `./proc1 && ./proc2` and not *in different terminals.*

Also you could use **pipes**, if you need to, ask me in the comments, I will describe

Comment: Just a minor suggestion, it's not that the i386 is specifically made to protect the process address space. That's a feature of whatever operating system you're running. Process isolation can be done on ARM, MIPS and other architectures too.